# Find fontspec name for font lmr and increase its size in select portions of document

Tags: xetex, fontspec

On my mac running OSX 11.0.1 and TeX Live 2020,  I'm trying to find the fontspec-name for the default font used by latex so that I can increase the font size in some locations of my document.

By using `\showthe\font` in a latex document, I printed the default font used on my Mac:
`\TU/lmr/m/n/10 .`

How do I find the fontspec name for `lmr`? `grep lmr $(kpsewhich pdftex.map)` returns 244 lines of output. How do I gather the exact font name for `lmr`? For e.g. from these three lines, I picked up `LMRoman10-Regular` as the possible fontspect-name:

```
ts1-lmr10 LMRoman10-Regular " enclmts1 ReEncodeFont " <lm-ts1.enc <lmr10.pfb
ts1-lmr12 LMRoman12-Regular " enclmts1 ReEncodeFont " <lm-ts1.enc <lmr12.pfb
ts1-lmr17 LMRoman17-Regular " enclmts1 ReEncodeFont " <lm-ts1.enc <lmr17.pfb
```

However, compiling my document fails when I use any variant of the names from the second column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% Tried LMRoman10, LMRoman, LMRoman10-Regular but nothing works
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1.0]{LMRoman10}
\begin{document}
% This text should be in normal size 
hello world

% Increase font size for this text
Print me in bigger size
\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Wouldn't `\large`, `\Large` or similar work? That said, yes, this is “Latin Modern”. If you want to access it via `fontspec` you'll probably need to install it on your system regularly, i.e. as a True/Open Type Font.

Comment: Give `\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}` a try. Aside: You needn't know the name of the default font in order to execute `{\large ...}` or `{\Huge ...}`.

Comment: what is wrong with `\fontsize{3cm}{4cm}\selectfont` ? why do you need to know th einternal names? Also latin modern is the default already in xelaetx so you do not need `fontspec` or the `\setmainfont` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The names of the default serif, sans-serif, and monospaced fonts that are employed if `fontspec` is loaded are `Latin Modern Roman`, `Latin Modern Sans`, and `Latin Modern Mono`.

Take the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman} % that's the default
\begin{document}
% normal size 
Hello world

% Increase relative font size to "\Huge" (ca. 73% larger than "\normalsize")
{\Huge Print me in ``\textbackslash Huge'' size.}
\end{document}
```

If I compile this sample document with either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTEX -- aside: I run MacTeX2020 under MacOS 11.1 "Big Sur" -- and consult the log file, I find the following information close to the end of the file:

```
</Users/mico/Library/Fonts/lmroman17-regular.otf>
</Users/mico/Library/Fonts/lmroman10-regular.otf>
```

If I changed `\documentclass{article}` to `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`, the log file would provide the following information:

```
</Users/mico/Library/Fonts/lmroman17-regular.otf>
</Users/mico/Library/Fonts/lmroman12-regular.otf>
```

Observe that `fontspec` performs the required mapping from the font name to the files that contain the glyphs at various sizes automatically. Unless you have a truly unusual font face, no user-level knowledge of the file names that contain the glyphs at various sizes is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Latin Modern is the default font in xelatex, and you should never need to know the internal font names, standard commands such as `\large` or `\fontsize` can be used without reference to internal names.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
% This text should be in normal size 
hello world

% Increase font size for this text
\fontsize{3cm}{3.5cm}\selectfont
Print me in bigger size
\end{document}
```