# why could not found font when explicit specify

Tags: fonts

when I am using this command to check the latex document fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\fontname\font
hello world!
\end{document}
```

it shows like this:

```
”[lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;” at 10.0pthello world!
```

then I set main fonts like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{lmroman10-regular}

\begin{document}
hello world!
\end{document}
```

it tell me could not find the fonts. the `mroman10-regular` fonts are the document using fonts, why could not found the fonts when I specify explicit？

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579048/find-fontspec-name-for-font-lmr-and-increase-its-size-in-select-portions-of-docu

Comment: the tex name is not necessarly the file name, and xelatex is picky (with lualatex it works). Use \setmainfont{lmroman10-regular.otf}

Comment: could you explain why it works?